# I want to display individual categories (wordpress) on page, but be able to fully style each category title

Tags: html, wordpress, categories

I am nearing the end of a project and one of the last things I need to do is take some static html divs and enter category links into them.

The thumbnails have transitions styled into them, so when a user hovers over, the category title will appear over the top of a css mask effect.

http://lukwebdesign.co.uk/projects/chinwe-roy/

The thumbnails are towards the bottom of the home page, so any suggestions as to what to look at would be much appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few ways to do this(especially depending on your setup) so I'm gonna have to make some assumptions on your site.

I'm assuming you're using default Wordpress posts and categories and not custom post types.

```
<?php
        //Get the terms in the taxonomy "category" and assign it to the variable $terms
        $terms = get_terms ('category');

        //Use a foreach loop to loop through the terms
        //i.e. for each term (e.g. workshop, exhibitions etc) do something
        foreach ($terms as $term) {
            //html for each category goes here
            //e.g. display thumnail/featured image/display category title/link
        }
?>
```

So for example within your foreach loop you could out each category url like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url() . '/' . $term -> taxonomy . '/' . $term -> slug;?>">
    <?php echo $term -> name; ?>
</a>
```

So for each category you can output a div and style it accordingly.